# How to compare contents in a list in haskell, to see if they are partially same?

Tags: list, haskell, set

This is very tricky for me.

Given a very long list,

> [[100,11,1,0,40,1],[100,12,3,1,22,23],[101,11,1,0,45,1],[101,12,3,1,28,30],[102,11,1,0,50,1],[102,12,3,1,50,50],[103,11,1,0,50,1],[103,12,3,1,50,50],[104,11,1,0,50,25],[104,12,3,1,50,50],[105,11,1,0,50,49],[105,12,3,0,30,30],[106,11,1,0,50,49],[106,12,3,0,25,26],[107,11,1,1,33,20],[107,12,3,0,25,26],[108,11,1,1,2,1],[108,12,3,1,20,24],[109,11,1,1,2,1],[109,12,3,1,28,31],[110,11,1,0,40,1],[110,12,3,1,22,23]..]

Now igore the first number of each list, if two lists are the same in spite of the first number, for example

> [101,11,1,0,50,1] `alike` [102,11,1,0,50,1]

We keep the latter list, until the whole list is all checked. Ideally the result should be like :

> [[102,11,1,0,50,1],[103,12,3,1,50,50]..]

My idea is to use map to take the first number away, use nub and \\ to get rid of all repeat results, make it into like

> [[11,1,0,50,1],[12,3,1,50,50],[12,3,1,50,50],[11,1,0,50,49],[12,3,0,25,26],[11,1,1,2,1],[11,1,0,40,1],[12,3,1,22,23],[11,1,0,45,1],[12,3,1,28,30]..]

and use Set.isSubsetOf to filter the orignal list out.

However, this idea is too complex and difficult to implenment. Since I am a beginner of Haskell, is there a better way to sort this? Or I can use a recursion function instead(still need efforts though)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your description, I take it you want to get a list of the last lists to possess each of the unique tails. You can do it like this:

```
lastUniqueByTail :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [[a]] 
lastUniqueByTail = reverse . nubBy ((==) `on` tail) . reverse
```

***Note*** this only works for finite lists of non-empty lists

You can find `on` in the `Data.Function` module, and you can find `nubBy` in `Data.List`.

So here's an explanation on each part, we'll work from the inside out:

- `` ((==) `on` tail) `` This function performs comparisons between two lists, and determines them to be equal if their tails are equal (i.e. it performs an equality check ignoring the first element).

  The `on` function is what is doing most of the magic here. It has the following type signature:

  ```
  on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
  ```

  And it is essentially defined as `` (f `on` g) x y = f (g x) (g y) ``, so substituting the functions we provided, we get `` ((==) `on` tail) x y = (tail x) == (tail y) ``.
- Then, `nubBy` is like `nub` except that you can provide it a comparator to test equality on. We give it the function we defined above so that it discards elements with the same tail.
- But, like `nub`, `nubBy` keeps the *first* element in each equivalence class it finds. (i.e. if it finds two elements that are equal in the list, it always picks the first). We want the last such elements, which is why we must reverse first (so that the last element that would have been equal becomes the first, and so is kept).
- Finally, we reverse at the end to get the order back how it was to begin with.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to do this on infinite lists anyway. You could never be sure that an element was the last one, so could never return anything.

Comment: Which is precisely the reason why it doesn't work for infinite lists ;) I was just making the restriction clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to compact a list by merging all items with same tail, try this code.

```
compactList:: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
compactList list = reverse $ compactList' list [] 

compactList':: [[Int]] -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
compactList' [] res = res
compactList' (l:ls) res
    | inList l res
    = compactList' ls res
    | otherwise
    = compactList' ls  (l:res)

inList :: [Int] -> [[Int]] -> Bool
inList [] _ = False
inList _ [] = False
inList val@(x:xs) ((x':xs'):ls)
    | xs == xs'
    = True
    | otherwise
    = inList val ls
```

If we need "keep the latter list" (I missed that previously), then just change the place of `reverse`

```
compactList list = reverse $ compactList' list []
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this code may not well fit with my case, but it gives me a good approach in thinking ;)

Comment: This code merges same items and keep unique tail. Add another function: import Data.List

comList :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
comList list = list \\ compactList list 
helps me get the answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just find the Euclidian distance between 2 vectors. For example, if you have two lists [a0, a1, ... , an] and [b0, b1, ..., bn], then the square of the Euclidian distance between them would be

```
sum [ (a - b) ^ 2 | (a, b) <- zip as bs ]
```

This can give you an idea of how *close* one list is to another. Ideally you should take the square root, but for what you are doing, I don't know if that is necessary.

Edit:

Sorry I misunderstood your question. According to your definition, `alike` is defined so:

```
alike as bs = (tail as) == (tail bs)
```

If that is the case, then something like the following should do the trick:

```
xAll [] = []
xAll xa@(x:xaa) = a : xAll b
    where
        a = last $ filter (alike x) xa
        b = filter (\m -> not (alike x m)) xa
```

But not sure if this is what you are looking for ...

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite understand how this may help in my case. I think I need to use recursion function instead?